# What's best for ecommerce site blog: weak cms or wordpress on subdomain?

Tags: seo, subdomain

I wanted to open a blog to generate some SEO benefits for an ecommerce website, so I contacted the company that hosts our website. The site platform offers a CMS option from which I could write articles, but it is nothing more than a wysiwyg editor.

The only main alternative offered to me was for me to create a wordpress blog on a domain I control (otherdomain.com/blog) that would then be served up on a subdomain at blog.ecommercesite.com.

I've been told their server operates on asp, so installing wordpress to their server isn't an option, and even installing some asp-based blog platform would then have to be custom installed to their server and the costs for doing this would "outweigh the benefits."

I'm not a big fan of any of these options, but which would have the best chance of creating a real SEO benefit?

Answer (score 0):

Real SEO it depend on your SEO strategies that how you do SEO for your blog & Site.

According to my experience Its ok that you are using your desired platform for your website. But for Blog , use wordpress because it is good , easy and user friendly CMS. Even a non-technical person also can handle blog if setup through wordpress.

In concern of SEO also wordpress having many good plugins for onpage SEO , SEO report , SEO analysis , Sitemap and a lot more. So I suggest you to use Wordpress CMS for BLOG.

Comment: Thanks. 
I do have some experience with wordpress, so I know how powerful it can be. I'm mostly curious if its benefits would outweigh the SEO drawbacks of it being on the subdomain as opposed to the main domain. If I understand your answer correctly, you're saying wordpress solution on the subdomain is still the better option.

Comment: Yes , you are right. Also for SEO I suggest you that make blog url like www.yourmainsite.com/blog instead of blog.yourmainsite.com

Comment: I can't- for reasons I explained in the main post, it can't be done at a www.yourmainsite.com/blog, but only at blog.yourmainsite.com

This exact problem is the essence of my question.

Comment: ok no issues. That was just suggestion.